# How to post photo with website clickthrough on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

Is it possible to post a photo on Facebook that links to a website?

Can this only be done with Facebook ads?

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot make an uploaded image on Facebook as a link itself in your post, like some kind of a banner. Although you can post the image and write the link in its comments field.

Otherwise, which is closer on what you want, you can post a link directly top , after 1 second it will show a preview of a link by displaying the first image that exists to the linked website where also gives you the option to choose between other available images that have been fetched from the linked website.

In the second scenario you cannot upload a custom image, you can only choose the ones that've been fetched as described.